# How is "Bonus Slag damage" calculated for Slag-Licked?

Tags: borderlands-2

I noticed I was gaining progress toward Slag Licked while using a Slag SMG:

> Slag-Licked: Deal some bonus damage to the slagged enemies (5000).

Slag does bonus damage to enemies when hit by *other* weapons but I generally don't swap from my slag gun to deal bonus damage; I let teammates shoot slagged enemies and I either keep firing or slag more enemies.

Does damage dealt from slag weapons count as "bonus slag" damage or am I getting a bonus from my *friends* dealing damage to slagged targets or what?

Comment: Upon further thought I think I was getting the bonus damage stat because of my Corrosive Cloud skill as a Siren, which deals extra non-slag damage after a bullet hits. I maxed out the challenge though so I can't easily test this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are the only one who can add to your challenges, save for one or two specific ones like the car compacter in the dust. So your friends hitting enemies you've slagged doesn't add to the bonus slag damage the challenge has said you've dealt (although it does add to your friends challeneges, since they're the ones dealing the bonus damage), and slag weapons don't deal any *bonus* damage, only their own damage.

As someone has said you do indeed need to switch to another weapon after slagging an enemy to deal bonus damage. It's also possible to use slag explosive barrels or, since you seem to be playing as the Siren, using  the ruin or scorn skills.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to have mostly been my Cloud Kill skill, I always forget I have that set.

Answer (score -2):

Slag weapons automatically apply their own damage bonus.  For example, when I got a slag sniper rifle early on it had 250 weapon damage, but actually hit for 300 (non-crit)

Comment: That is not how they are supposed to work, you need to switch to a different weapons for the additional damage. Was this 300 damage after the first 250 dam shot hit? Or not? If it wasn't perhaps you had other damage bonuses. 20% bonus damage isn't that strange with the right badass and class bonus.

Comment: In fact, I think that once slagged, they are *resistant* to slagged weapons IIRC.

Comment: @horatio they aren't, they just continue to take normal damage from slag weapons. They don't take double damage either though, I know that for sure. You probably just hit a lower level enemy, which translates to higher damage. Slag bonus is 2x.

Comment: Enemies that have slagged in their name (Slagged spiderants, rakks, psychos) are completely resistant to slag. My 27k+ damage e-tech sniper did 1 or no damage to them, for example.

Comment: Note for future readers: In Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode, slag weapons [get a 50% bonus as well](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Slag#Effectiveness).